# Не могу понять, что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, синтаксис

```
s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')
```

Из этого мне понятно только то, что `X_train.dtypes` - это обьект типа Series. С ним чего-то происходит, судя по всему, каждая строка серии последовательно проверяется на соответствие типу object и в `s` записывается Series c логическими результатами этого соответствия.

Вопрос: Что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Подскажите название, я хоть погуглю.

[image: X_train.dtypes]
[image: Значение S]

Comment: Это булева маска. в нее записывается "истина" или "ложь" (True/False) в зависимости от того, верно ли выражение в скобках для каждого конкретного элемента серии.

Comment: да, в s записать булевое True или False в зависимости от результата сравнения X_train.dtypes == 'object'

Comment: В общем-то это обычная *векторная* операция, если вы хотите работать с `Pandas` и `Numpy`, то вам придётся научиться мыслить *векторно*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данной конструкции создается булева маска - она обычно используется для фильтрования `pandas.Series` / `pandas.DataFrame` / `numpy.NDArray`.

Например так можно выбрать все столбцы с типом данных `object`:

```
mask = X_train.dtypes == 'object'
str_cols = X_train.columns[mask]
```

или наоборот столбцы с любым типом данных **отличным от `object`**:

```
non_str_cols = X_train.columns[~mask]
```

С точки зрения синтаксиса, в Pandas и Numpy переопределены все основные операторы и таким образом мы можем применять операторы к векторам и матрицам, которые мы в обычном Python применяем к скалярам. И получать в результате вектора и матрицы. Т.е. как сказал @CrazyElf в комментариях, при работе с Pandas/Numpy нужно научиться мыслить и работать "векторно". Это позволит вам писать эффективный и красивый код без (или почти без) использования циклов.

Comment: Спасибо! А какую роль в этом случае играют круглые скобки? Я их видел до этого только при инициализации кортежей, но это вроде не тот случай.

Comment: @Disciple, круглые скобки здесь используются для явного задания приоритета выполнения операций. Т.е. сначала выполняется операция в скобках (как в алгебре), а потом присваивание результата выражения в скобках переменной `s`